# .Net Core App Fatal Error Initialising Blob Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am in the process of migrating an ASP.Net MVC app to .Net Core 2.1. In the ConfigureServices function in the Startup class I called logic that runs the following (to initialize a log file stored in Blob storage):

```
var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

var client = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference(Container);
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
var blob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(LogFileName);
if (!await blob.ExistsAsync())
    await blob.CreateOrReplaceAsync();
```

However though the log file is created the application disappears in a puff of smoke. Wrapping things in a try/catch block doesn't actually catch the error. Removing the code fixes the issue. This used to run under the old site on startup just fine, so I am wondering if there is something obvious I am missing?

[Edit] I forgot to add, the log file does actually get created.

Comment: Not all exception can be catched with a `try-catch` block. You should check your server logs, to see if there is something special?

Comment: Where is your connectionString coming from? Because there are some things you need to do to get values from (for instance) `appSettings.json`

Comment: The connection string is coming from our settings for the app service in Azure

Comment: I forgot to add (and I have edited my initial question) that the log file does actually get created.